# iOS Crash during background data processing when adding NSOperations to NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My app is getting a 'random' crash when doing some background data processing. I am adding `NSOperations` (subclassed) to an array, then adding that array of `NSOperations` to a `NSOperationQueue`.

I am seeing 3-4 errors which all point to the this line in the stack trace:

```
[_operationQueue addOperations:_operationsArray waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

Here is how I am creating my `NSOperations` (`LibSyncOperation`) and adding them to `_operationsArray`, which eventually gets added to the `_operationQueue`

```
LibSyncOperation *libSyncOperation = [[LibSyncOperation alloc] initWithURL:path];    
if(!libSyncOperation.isExecuting && !libSyncOperation.isFinished)
{
    [_operationsArray addObject:libSyncOperation];
    TFLog(@"Operation is *NOT* Executing, add to OperationQueue");
}
else
{
    TFLog(@"Operation is already Executing, do not add to OperationQueue");
}
```

Here are some of the stack traces:

```
*** -[NSOperationQueue addOperations:waitUntilFinished:]: 3 (of 4) operations are finished, executing, or already in a queue, and cannot be enqueued
CoreFoundation-[NSException initWithCoder:]

0   CoreFoundation  0x18835f09c __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x1947b5d78 objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  0x18835efdc -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3   Foundation  0x188ec1864 __addOperations
4   Foundation  0x188ec1bfc -[NSOperationQueue addOperations:waitUntilFinished:]
5   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x100223b54 __70-[NetworkManager checkForDataFilesShouldEmptyQueue:isInitialDownload:]_block_invoke_2183 in NetworkManager.m on Line 437
6   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d84420 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d843e0 _dispatch_client_callout
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d8b3fc _dispatch_root_queue_drain
9   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d8b638 _dispatch_worker_thread2
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x194f19918 _pthread_wqthread
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x194f197a8 start_wqthread
```

Another:

```
*** Collection <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x1784402a0> was mutated while being enumerated.
CoreFoundation

0   CoreFoundation  0x186226f50 
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x192c041fc objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  0x186226984 
3   Foundation  0x186d91928 -[NSOperationQueue addOperations:waitUntilFinished:]
4   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x1002bbb54 __70-[NetworkManager checkForDataFilesShouldEmptyQueue:isInitialDownload:]_block_invoke_2183 in NetworkManager.m on Line 437
5   libdispatch.dylib   0x1931dc014 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
6   libdispatch.dylib   0x1931dbfd4 _dispatch_client_callout
7   libdispatch.dylib   0x1931e32b8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x1931e34fc _dispatch_worker_thread2
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1933716bc _pthread_wqthread
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x19337154c start_wqthread
```

Last One:

```
-[__NSBlockVariable__ countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1782499c0
CoreFoundation__methodDescriptionForSelector


0   CoreFoundation  0x18835f09c __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x1947b5d78 objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  0x188363d14 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3   CoreFoundation  0x188361a7c ___forwarding___
4   CoreFoundation  0x1882814ac __forwarding_prep_0___
5   Foundation  0x188ec1ca0 -[NSOperationQueue addOperations:waitUntilFinished:]
6   Tower-iSales-Tab    0x1002afb54 __70-[NetworkManager checkForDataFilesShouldEmptyQueue:isInitialDownload:]_block_invoke_2183 in NetworkManager.m on Line 437
7   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d84420 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d843e0 _dispatch_client_callout
9   libdispatch.dylib   0x194d8b3fc _dispatch_root_queue_drain
10  libdispatch.dylib   0x194d8b638 _dispatch_worker_thread2
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x194f19918 _pthread_wqthread
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x194f197a8 start_wqthread
```

Is there some obvious reason this crash would occur? I understand what the error message is saying, that `NSOperations` that are executing or finished cannot be enqueued again, the thing is, my `_operationsArray` is re-allocating anytime the update process runs, to ensure there are no `NSOperations` that were already enqueued hanging around.

One thing I am not doing, is re-allocating the NSOperationQueue each time, I figure that could be the cause, but since I cannot reproduce the error on my end (the users are experiencing this), I would like to know for sure. Heres the code for my NSOperationQueue (note this is all in a singleton class)

```
    if(!_operationQueue)
        _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

    [_operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

Could this be the culprit?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

As requested, heres the `main` for my LibSyncOperation:

```
-(void)main
{
    if (![self isCancelled])
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        executing = YES;

        NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:9999999];

        NSURLConnection *downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];

        [downloadConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [downloadConnection start]; 

        if (downloadConnection) 
        {
            do
            {
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
            } while (!downloadDone);

            [self terminateOperation];
        }
        else
        {
            [self terminateOperation];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self terminateOperation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the LibSyncOperation code please?  Also why do you have a check right after you have initialized it to see if it is running or finished?  You haven't called `start` or added it to an operation queue yet.

Comment: Also make sure you are emptying the _operationsArray after loading it into the operation queue.  I can't see the rest of your code here but I have a hunch and besides you don't need to retain those operations at that point anyway.  In fact I would do away with that ivar if you can and just created a new local NSMutableArray each time you want to add a collection of operations if you don't need to persist the state.

Comment: I know that it is not really necessary (the check), that was one of the things I just tried initially. Which part of the LibSyncOperation would you like to see, main()?? It is quite a lot of code to post.

Comment: Try the change I am suggesting first with the _operationsArray ivar.  Can you get rid of it and just use a local variable or empty it after you have added it?  There are several reasons you don't want those operations hanging around in that collection that might have something to do with this.

Comment: If that doesn't work, yes post the main method.

Comment: By the way, if you want to put safety code in to make sure a condition is what you expect use NSAssert or NSParameterAssert, don't wrap the whole thing in an if block like that.  NSAssert will cause the app to terminate and throw an exception that is easy to trace down in dev mode but will not affect the performance of your application when built for release, thus protecting you against code bugs but not adding complexity to your app.  Trust me, you'll write much more defensive code by adding some simple uses of NSAssert and NSParameterAssert.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and see if it helps. As I said I am unable to re-produce on my end, so I will not know right away if it helps, so I added main() to my question so you can peak at that. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh boy...why on Earth are you scheduling the NSURLConnection on the run loop and assigning a delegate to the operation instead of just calling it synchronously?  This is a background operation, it doesn't run on the main thread so you don't need to add such needless complexity (and even if this was a main thread operation you could cleanup a ton by just using the `sendAsynchronousRequest:` method.  Also you really shouldn't set the timeout interval to infinite like that, just use the normal `requestWithURL:` method.

Comment: Also why do you have all that code for `isCancelled` and `isExecuting`?  Do you know how NSOperation works?  What are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: Honestly, I was given the class in an existing project and has worked fine for the most part. That being said, I would not call myself an expert on NSOperation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52133/discussion-between-smyrgl-and-ryang)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? we are having it too on our app.

Comment: Unfortunately my solution was to re-do my networking logic. I am no longer using NSOperations. I am now using AFNetworking 2.0, subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager and using GDC.